# Parsing JSON streams

Tags: jquery, json

I feel like I have had this problem before but im having a hard time parsing this JSON response. Maybe I'm just having a mental block. Can one of you guide me in the right direction.

```
jQuery(function() {
    //Conv Data
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: NewConvData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) { 
            var channelHTML = '';
            jQuery.each(response, function (i, item) {
                channelHTML += '<tr><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.call_mine_status + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.cdr_source + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.tracking_number + '%</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.disposition + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.duration + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.external_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.is_outbound + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.ouid + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.repeat_call + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.caller_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.calldate + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.ringto_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l"><a href="' + item.file_url + '">Recorded Call</a></td></tr>';
            });
            jQuery('#conv_table').append(channelHTML);              
        }   
    });     
});
```

The JSON response looks like this:

```
    {
  "status": "success",
  "matches": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "call_mine_status": "not mined",
      "cdr_source": "CE",
      "tracking_number": "9999999999",
      "disposition": "ANSWERED",
      "duration": 284,
      "external_id": null,
      "id": 25039100,
      "is_outbound": 0,
      "ouid": 49677,
      "repeat_call": false,
      "caller_id": "1234567891",
      "calldate": "2015-12-01 13:50:03",
      "ringto_number": "2223334444",
      "title": null,
      "user_id": null,
      "scored": false,
      "call_value": null,
      "indicator": {
        "active_indicators": [

        ],
        "custom_indicators": [

        ]
      },
      "tagged": false,
      "mine_error": "",
      "call_recorded": "92cda5a0-3929-4773-9d4b-1a8deb14570c",
      "postcall_response": [
        {
          "postcall_ivr_type": null,
          "postcall_ivr_response": null
        }
      ],
      "postcall_option": [
        {
          "option_order": 1,
          "details": [
            {
              "postcall_ivr_enabled": "false",
              "postcall_ivr_tts": null,
              "postcall_ivr_type": null,
              "postcall_ivr_digits": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "transaction_id": 354203610
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: `file_url` doesn't exist in your JSON response.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting an undefined error in table that is supposed to contain the Jason data

Comment: Highly improbable that the api is CORS enabled if it requires using secret keys. Those should never be exposed in browser

Comment: I updated the JS, but im still getting the same result, undefined errors across the table.

Comment: may be `JSON.parse("[1:'e',  2:'a'}")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i'm entirely clear on what you're looking for.  Perhaps [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

Your `jQuery.each` might be encountering some problems since `data` isn't an array.  I'm actually not sure why you're using that at all.  Try `var item = data[0]` since `.results` doesn't exist and remove that `.each` function.

Comment: "im having a hard time parsing this JSON response". @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

By adding: for (var i in data.results) i was able to get it to work.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.getJSON(NewConvData, function(data){
        var channelHTML = ''
        jQuery.each(data, function(i){
            console.log(data);
            for (var i in data.results) {
            channelHTML += '<tr><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].call_mine_status + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].cdr_source + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].tracking_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].disposition + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].duration + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].external_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].is_outbound + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].ouid + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].repeat_call + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].caller_id + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].calldate + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + data.results[i].ringto_number + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l"><a href="' + data.results[i].file_url + '">Recorded Call</a></td></tr>';
            }
        });
        jQuery('#conv_table').append(channelHTML);
    });              
});
```